# gensym for TeX?

Tags: macros, plain-tex

In other macro systems (notably Lisp's), one often needs to store results into "temporary" variables which shouldn't clash with any variables in the environment where the macro is called. In Lisp, the mechanism for declaring such variables is "gensym"---basically it is a function that returns a fresh variable name that is guaranteed to be unused anywhere else.

It does this essentially by appending an increasing integer onto a variable name prefix. [This is essentially correct, but slightly a lie. Lisp has to do some symbol magic to ensure the variable can't be referred to anywhere else.]

Is there such a capability in Plain TeX?

Comment: `\begingroup`-`\endgroup`?

Comment: that's true. { and } manage scope properly, unlike Lisp. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing of this kind in TeX. However, any macro defined inside a group (which can be initiated in several different ways) will not be accessible outside that group, unless defined with `\gdef` or `\xdef` (or if `\globaldefs` is positive). So

```
{\def\temp{something}...}
```

will possibly clobber the meaning of `\temp` inside the group, but that meaning will be restored at the end of the group or, if `\temp` was undefined to begin with, it will disappear completely.